# Specying the positive class in pROC package

Tags: r, classification, roc, auc, proc-r-package

I want to calculate different classification metrics (sensitivity, specificity) using pROC package. For that, I can use `coords` function in `pROC` package as:

```
# Load library
library(pROC) 
# Load data
data(aSAH)
#Convert Good and Poor to 1 and 0
aSAH$outcome <- ifelse(aSAH$outcome=="Good", 1, 0)
# Calculate ROC
rocobj <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b)
# Get sensitivity and specificity
coords(rocobj, 0.55)
```

Here it takes `1` as positive class, i.e. may be the class that is most prevalent but I am not sure.  I was wondering, if it possible to use '0' as the positive class. 
For example you can do that in `caret` package's `confusionMatrix` function as:

```
confusionMatrix(factor(as.numeric(aSAH$s100b<0.55),levels=c('0','1')),
                   factor(aSAH$outcome,levels=c('0','1')), positive='1')
```

for `1` as positive and

```
confusionMatrix(factor(as.numeric(aSAH$s100b<0.55),levels=c('0','1')),
                   factor(aSAH$outcome,levels=c('0','1')), positive='0')
```

for `0` as positive class. I am using pROC package as it provides other functions such as determining the best cutoffs etc. which is not possible in caret. However, is there a way to specify positive and negative class in `pROC` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `levels` argument:

```
levels: the value of the response for controls and cases
          respectively.
```

Here "control" means a negative observation, and "case" is a positive one. The default choice is not based on prevalence, simply on the order of the first two values of `levels(as.factor(response))`.

To change it, pass a vector of length two such as:

```
rocobj <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b, levels = c(1, 0))
```

Note that it won't make a difference to your curve until you set the `direction` argument, which is on `"auto"` by default.